# Could not find or load main class , environment variables

Tags: java, class, load, find, program-entry-point

I know this has come up a number of times, but previous responses just don't seem to help.
My environment variables are :

- CLASSPATH  `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program
  Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;`
- PATH    `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;`

When moving to the directory as follows `C:\Users\Oli\My Documents\java` I can compile using `javac`, but cannot runt he program using java. I know its most likely got something to do with environment variables but I cannot get it to work. P.S the error is "*could not find or load main class*"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

CLASSPATH is the place where JRE looks for classes. You've set your CLASSPATH to a value and expect to run the class from current Directory, which won't work.. for instant solution you may use

java -cp C:\Users\Oli\My Documents\java ClassName

Or undo setting CLASSPATH. Default CLASSPATH is current directory

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume that your ".java" file default package ( no package defined) survivies in "C:\Src"
You dont need to set the CLASSPATH in this case.

```
  cd C:\Src
  javac MyJava.java
  java MyJava
```

If with package say com.test

```
cd C:\Src
javac com\test\MyJava.java
java com.test.MyJava
```

However if you are not in the same folder as Source files and want to run from anywhere

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\src
javac MyJava.java or javac com\test\MyJava.java
```

and
    java com.test.MyJava or java com.test.MyJava

Answer (score 2):

Unset CLASSPATH and just use the default one provided by the JVM.  Here is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) to the Java Tutorial that covers the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is not in the path...
Does your code use the 'package' statement? (i.e. package my_package;)

If so, go to 'java' directory and execute:

java my_package.MyClass

where 'my_package' is the name of... the package, and MyClass is your compiled .java file (without the .class extension).

Good luck.